# "Service failed to start - Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services"

Tags: service, installation, wix

When I tried to run the installer that I created in WIX, the error message below occured:

"Service 'Report Generator Service' (Report Generator Service) failed to start. Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services".

I already read some blogs here about this by my codes are almost identical but still this error keeps popping out. The weird thing about this is that when I first created this installer with almost the same code as below, this error is not happening during installation. Please help me guys I'm lost... :(

```
<File Id="ReportGenerator.exe"
                                Name="ReportGenerator.exe"
                                Source="..\ReportGenerator\bin\Release\ReportGenerator.exe"
                                KeyPath="yes" />
                          <ServiceInstall Id="ReportGeneratorServiceInstaller"
                                              Name="ReportGeneratorInstaller"
                                              DisplayName="Report Generator Service"
                                              Type="ownProcess"
                                              Start="auto"
                                              ErrorControl="normal"
                                              Description="Generate Reports"
                                              Account="[SERVICEACCOUNT]"
                                              Password="[SERVICEPASSWORD]" />
                          <ServiceControl Id="StartReportService"
                                          Start="install"
                                          Stop="both"
                                          Remove="uninstall"
                                          Name="ReportGeneratorInstaller"
                                          Wait="yes" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your service relies on assemblies being installed into the GAC, you won't be able to start it using ServiceControl. GAC'd assemblies aren't present until the install is committed, which is too late for ServiceControl to work.

Comment: sorry what do you mean by "If your service relies on assemblies being installed into the GAC"?

Comment: @furanzu GAC is Global Assembly Cache. If you install assemblies (DLLs) into GAC, the service can't start until they're installed and registered.

Comment: I am facing the same issue in one of my setup.
I am unable to understand the abouve answer.
Please explain a bit.

Answer (score 3):

This error can also happen if the Service Account doesn't have "Log on as a service" permission. To fix this

- Open SecPol.msc
- Navigate to Local Policies/User Rights Assigment
- Find "Log on as a service" policy and add the service account

*I'm mentioning this here because a Google search for the above error lists this link in the first page. :) someone might find this useful*